# How to check if a V6 ip belongs to a subnet using bitwise operation

Tags: ipv6

I have a V6 ip like 6000::8000:1/128. I need to check if this ip lies within a subnet of say, 6000::8000:0/112.

I want to use bitwise operation. Can somebody please help me with the logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: he mentioned bitwise ops, so there shouldn't be that much dependence on the programming language.

Comment: C or c++ bitwise operation

Answer (score 0):

I had reason to do something similar, so I thought I'd chime in 3.5 years later.

My solution is fairly brittle, but essentially I just convert the address and network into char arrays using `inet_pton()`, and then iterate over each byte (or fraction thereof, depending on the length of the netmask) of the address and network to compare whether the bits differ. However, this solution handles both IPv4 and IPv6.

Invoke as `./a.out 2001::/64 2001::1234` where the first argument is the network/netmask and the second is the address to determine whether the network contains.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef struct {
    char netaddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char * straddr;
    int netmask;
    int domain;
} network;

//Parses a address/netmask string
network * parseNetwork(char * str) {

    network * retnet;
    char * slashptr;

    retnet = (network *) malloc(sizeof(network));

    //Parse the netmask
    if ((slashptr = strchr(str, '/')) == NULL) {
        retnet->netmask = 0;
    } else {
        slashptr++;
        retnet->netmask = atoi(slashptr);
        --slashptr;
        *slashptr = '\0';
    }

    //Parse the network portion
    if (strchr(str, ':') != NULL)  {
        //this is v6
        retnet->domain = AF_INET6;
        if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, str, retnet->netaddr) <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, 
                    "Error converting IPv6 address to network format\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (retnet->netmask > 128 || retnet->netmask < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[-] IPv6 subnet mask must be 0 <= x <= 128\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    } else if (strchr(str, '.') != NULL) {
        //this is v4
        retnet->domain = AF_INET;
        if (inet_pton(AF_INET, str, retnet->netaddr) <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, 
                    "Error converting IPv4 address to network format\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (retnet->netmask > 32 || retnet->netmask < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[-] IPv4 subnet mask must be 0 <= x <= 32\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    retnet->straddr = strdup(str);

    return retnet;

}

void printNetwork(network * net)
{
    printf("Netaddr: %s\n", net->straddr);
    printf("Netmask: %d\n", net->netmask);
    printf("Domain: %s\n", net->domain == AF_INET ? "IPv4" : "IPv6");
}

int networkContainsAddr(network * net, network * addr)
{

    int res = 0;
    int maskbits = net->netmask;
    int end;

    if (net->domain == AF_INET) {
        end = 4;
    } else {
        end = 16;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < end && maskbits > 0 && res == 0; i++)
    {
        int bytebits, bytemask, netbits, addrbits;

        //# bits on in mask for this byte
        bytebits = (maskbits >= 8) ? 8 : maskbits;         
        //bitmask for this byte
        bytemask = pow((double) 2, (double) bytebits) - 1; 
        //mask out bits in network
        netbits = (net->netaddr[i] & (bytemask << (8 - bytebits)));         
        //mask out bits in ? address
        addrbits = (addr->netaddr[i] & (bytemask << (8 - bytebits)));    
        //result non-zero if bits differ
        res = netbits ^ addrbits; 
        maskbits -= bytebits;
    }

    return res;

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int result;
    network * net, * addr;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Usage: %s network/netmask address\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    net = parseNetwork(argv[1]);
    printNetwork(net);
    addr = parseNetwork(argv[2]);
    printNetwork(addr);

    result = networkContainsAddr(net, addr);

    printf("%s is%s in %s/%d\n", addr->straddr, result ? " not" : "", 
                                 net->straddr, net->netmask);

    free(net->straddr);
    free(net);
    free(addr->straddr);
    free(addr);
    

    return 0;
}
```